Can't create EKS Node group with Terraform
I created an EKS cluster first, then create node group with Terraform.
data "aws_region" "current" {}

data "aws_iam_policy_document" "eks_worker_node_assume_role" {
  statement {
    effect = "Allow"

    principals {
      type        = "Service"
      identifiers = ["ec2.amazonaws.com"]
    }

    actions = ["sts:AssumeRole"]
  }
}

resource "aws_iam_role" "eks_worker_node_assume_role" {
  name               = "AmazonEKSWorkNodeAssumeRole"
  assume_role_policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.eks_worker_node_assume_role.json
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "AmazonEKSWorkerNodePolicy" {
  policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonEKSWorkerNodePolicy"
  role       = aws_iam_role.eks_worker_node_assume_role.name
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "AmazonEKS_CNI_Policy" {
  policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonEKS_CNI_Policy"
  role       = aws_iam_role.eks_worker_node_assume_role.name
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "AmazonEC2ContainerRegistryReadOnly" {
  policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonEC2ContainerRegistryReadOnly"
  role       = aws_iam_role.eks_worker_node_assume_role.name
}

resource "aws_eks_node_group" "this" {
  cluster_name    = "my-cluster"
  node_group_name = "default"
  node_role_arn   = aws_iam_role.eks_worker_node_assume_role.arn

  subnet_ids = ["subnet1", "subnet2"]

  capacity_type  = "ON_DEMAND"
  instance_types = ["t3.small"]

  scaling_config {
    desired_size = 3
    max_size     = 6
    min_size     = 3
  }

  update_config {
    max_unavailable_percentage = 50
  }

  labels = {
    role = "managed-nodes"
  }

  tags = {
    "k8s.io/cluster-autoscaler/enabled" = "true"
    "k8s.io/cluster-autoscaler/cluster" = "owned"
  }

  depends_on = [
    aws_iam_role_policy_attachment.AmazonEKSWorkerNodePolicy,
    aws_iam_role_policy_attachment.AmazonEKS_CNI_Policy,
    aws_iam_role_policy_attachment.AmazonEC2ContainerRegistryReadOnly,
  ]
}

But got this error:
Your current IAM principal doesn’t have access to Kubernetes objects on this cluster.
Instances failed to join the kubernetes cluster

Why the assume IAM role doesn't work?

When I run kubectl edit configmap aws-auth -n kube-system then got this configMap:
apiVersion: v1
data:
  mapRoles: |
    - groups:
      - system:bootstrappers
      - system:nodes
      rolearn: arn:aws:iam::111111111111:role/AmazonEKSWorkNodeAssumeRole
      username: system:node:{{EC2PrivateDNSName}}
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: "2024-08-02T08:46:52Z"
  name: aws-auth
  namespace: kube-system
  resourceVersion: "5776"
  uid: 1111111111-2222-3333-4444-5555555555555

Is there anything mistake?
